# Angular v1 Component to Component data transfer

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6, directive, axios

I'm struggling with a problem within Angular v1.6.1 where I am trying to transfer some data from a component to another component.

---

I have a component called **navbar** which resides in `app\common\navbar` has a controller that fetches data from a service. The following files make up navbar component

**navbar.component.js**

```
import controller from './navbar.controller';
import template from './navbar.html';
export default navbarComponent = {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {},
  template,
  controller
};
```

**navbar.controller.js**

```
class NavbarController {
  constructor(httpService) {
    const dataUrl = "/assets/data/header.json";
    this.name = 'Navbar';
    this.headerData = {};
    console.log("In "+this.name);
    httpService.getData(dataUrl)
      .then((response) => {
          angular.extend(this.headerData,response.data);
      },(error) => { throw error; });
  }
}
export default NavbarController;
```

**navbar.html**

```
<section>
  <top-header top-data="$ctrl.headerData"></top-header>
<section>
```

---

and my **httpService** resides in `app\services` folder. It fetches content using `axios` http library and looks something like this

**httpService.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
export class HttpService {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "HttpService";
    }
    getData(api_url){
      return axios.get(api_url)
        .then((response) => response, (error) => error);
    }
}
```

---

The component which uses my `navbar` component's headerData is **top-header** and resides in `app\common\top-header`. This is what it contains

**top-header.component.js**

```
import template from './top-header.html';
import controller from './top-header.controller';

export default topHeaderComponent = {
  restrict: 'E',
  template,
  bindings: {
      topData: '<'
  },
  controller,
};
```

**top-header.controller.js**

```
class TopHeaderController {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'TopHeader';
    this.topHeaderData = {};
    this.$onInit = function() {
       this.topHeaderData = this.topData;
       console.log(this.topHeaderData);
       console.log(this.topHeaderData.telephoneNumber);
       console.log(this.topHeaderData);
    }
  }
}
export default TopHeaderController;
```

**top-header.html**

```
{{$ctrl.topHeaderData.telephoneNumber}}
```

---

and finally my static files resides in `assets\data` and the JSON I'm trying to fetch **header.json** contains

**header.json**

```
{
    "telephoneNumber": 12345678
}
```

---

So the problem now I see is that the data does show up in my top-header component but I'm not sure what's happening but the data disappears (comes up `undefined`) once I try to access the object property.

What I'm saying is that in **top-header.controller.js** 
 when I `console.log(this.topHeaderData);` it shows the object but when I try to `console.log(this.topHeaderData.telephoneNumber);` it comes up `undefined`

I think the problem exists because of the execution priority of the Directives. I even set `navbar` component priority to 5 and it didn't help as the data is undefined.

**top-header.controller.js**

```
this.$onInit = function() {
   this.topHeaderData = this.topData;
   console.log(this.topHeaderData); // shows topData
   console.log(this.topHeaderData.telephoneNumber);  // undefined
   console.log(this.topHeaderData); // shows topData
}
```

This data `this.topHeaderData.telephoneNumber` is essential as I use this in my template.

How can I resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in `top-header.controller.js`: you're assigning binded `topData` to `this.topheaderData` in `$onInit` hook but when component is initialized the data hasn't been fetched yet. Instead of `$onInit` you should use `$onChange` hook method which is called by Angular when binded property is updated (in your case when data is fetched from server)

Angular component docs:

> $onChanges(changesObj) - Called whenever one-way bindings are updated.
>   The changesObj is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound
>   properties that have changed, and the values are an object of the form
>   { currentValue, previousValue, isFirstChange() }. Use this hook to
>   trigger updates within a component such as cloning the bound value to
>   prevent accidental mutation of the outer value.